# `screen.getByText()` vs `getByText()` in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am building out tests in my React app that was built with create-react-app and I'm trying to understand what the difference is between `screen.getByText()` and simply `getByText()`. For instance, the documentation shows this kind of example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

it('renders a title of "Dashboard"', () => {
  render(<App />);
  expect(screen.getByText('Dashboard')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

But I see that I can do this:

```
it('renders a title of "Dashboard"', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(<App />);
  expect(getByText('Dashboard')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

I haven't found what the difference is between using `screen.getByText()` vs. simply using `getByText()` like I've shown above.

What are the differences, and are there advantages in using one over the other in various scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a convenience thing. Using `screen` you'll find that you no longer need to constantly/explicitly have to destructure the return value of the `render` method to get to the selector functions (that's basically it).

The PR that introduced the feature has a clear explanation of the rationale behind it:

https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/pull/412

The only caveat is in the scenario where you provide an explicit [`container` argument to the render method](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api/#container) - as the `screen` based selector would match all elements on the `document.body` (where as if you destructure the `render` result, the selector functions will be scoped to elements within the container you provided).

If you're starting out with that library I also suggest that you take a peek into this Kent Dodds article (the same who introduced the feature and a person which is a big reference in this area), which has a bunch of goodies/best practices using testing-library with the rationale behind each recommendation:

https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library